# MySqli statement execute returns false even if data gets inserted

Tags: php, mysqli, slim

Here is my simple slim application. This function below handles the insert.

```
public function createSelfie($user_id, $image, $latitude, $longitude) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_selfie(image, latitude, longitude, user_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $image, $latitude, $longitude, $user_id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
            // we were successful in storing the selfie now we need to manipulate the 'user_egg' table values
            return SELFIE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        }

        else {
            // selfie failed to create
            return NULL;
        }

    }
```

For this to work the route is as follows:

```
$app->post('/selfie/create', function() use ($app) {
            verifyRequiredParams(array('image', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'user_id'));

            // reading post params
            $image = $app->request()->post('image');
            $latitude = $app->request()->post('latitude');
            $longitude = $app->request()->post('longitude');
            $user_id = $app->request()->post('user_id');
            $response = array();

             $db = new DbHandler();
             $res = $db->createSelfie($user_id, $image, $latitude, $longitude);

             if ($res == SELFIE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response["message"] = "Your selfie created successfully";
                echoRespnse(201, $response);
             }

             else {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response["message"] = "There was an error storing your selfie try again";
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
             }

        });
```

Now sometimes it will respond correctly and sometimes null. But everytime the statement does get executed and i see row being inserted. Then I am perplexed why the function returns false. What could be the reason? and if we are not able to know the reason is it a good practice to use afftected_rows instead of result?.  On a side note I do have a echoRespnse method which json encodes the results and sends the response as json.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "return SELFIE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;"
try

```
return true;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. However, why do you think that will fix the problem. Anyway I am gonna try that out.

Comment: I'm assuming SELFIE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY is a variable that has no data and equals NULL or 0 which would make it return FALSE. Your using the function to return if the statement ran correctly TRUE or not FALSE. You return FALSE but do not return TRUE.

Comment: in my config.php I have declared it as a constant.
`define('SELFIE_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY', 3);`

So even after this, the point makes sense?. I assumed anything other than 0 would be true

Comment: By the way still the same problem persists.

Comment: Well any value other than 0 should be treated as TRUE so that can't be the issue I guess. Does it ALWAYS return false?? I would ECHO the $result to see what it's value actually is in each part of the code. Before, after, and in the IF statements. Might clarify what's happening. Also one other thing is the $result could lose it's data after CLOSE. Good luck.

Comment: No no it does not. However, I wrote the back-end service. There is another developer working on the iOS app. What I just realized now she is trying to save a large image. Which should not be the case. She should scale down the image and send. That might be making a delay at times and creating this failure but when all payload is transferred insert completes. I have asked her to scale the image to like 100px X 100px. Then will let you know. I know storing the image is bad idea in db but in this case its a compulsion. sorry about that.

Comment: Bingo! after image size is reduced it works. Now I wonder if it is indeed required to store a large   image  in mysql as base 64 encoded in a text field. How to approach that